# SQLiteException Unknown error

Tags: android, sqlite

Does anyone know what this means? I'm trying to start a transaction in onActivityResult() to insert a row based on the received result.

> 03-05 15:39:51.937:
>   ERROR/Database(2387): Failure 21 (out
>   of memory) on 0x0 when preparing
>   'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;'.
>
> 03-05 15:39:51.967:
>   DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2387): Shutting
>   down VM 03-05 15:39:51.967:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(2387): threadid=3:
>   thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40013140)
>
> 03-05 15:39:51.967:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2387): Uncaught
>   handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception
>
> 03-05 15:39:52.137:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2387):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure
>   delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,
>   request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.ozdroid/com.ozdroid.load.LoadView}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>   unknown error: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
>
> ...
>
> 03-05 15:39:52.137:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2387): Caused by:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>   unknown error: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
>
> ...
>
> 03-05 15:39:52.137:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2387):     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:434)

Answer (score 9):

I've had this happen to me in two situations:

1. when SQL statements contain syntax errors
2. when `beginTransaction` is called on a *not-open* database connection

It looks like you've run into number two. Check your syntax and make sure you `open()` (and don't `close()`) your database *before* you call `beginTransaction`.

And I think we can agree that the resulting `logcat` error messages are not 100% helpful.